# System.Net.WebClient and "DELETE" method

Tags: .net

If I call `System.Net.WebClient.UploadFile(fileUrl, "DELETE", localFileName)`, is the file at `localFileName` actually uploaded to the server?  Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you use UploadString instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a quick look at the `WebClient` code with Reflector, and it seems to upload the file even if the method is DELETE. I think a better way of doing this would be to use an `HttpWebRequest` explicitly, where you can specify the method without uploading the file